# How do I escape spaces in bash environment variables as an argument?

Tags: bash, variables, arguments, escaping, space

I have an environment variable that contains flags and arguments e.g.

```
export CMD='compile -m bla --vars "hello there"'
```

When I try to run `run ${CMD}`, the error says:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: there"
```

It doesn't register that the quotation belongs to "hello there".
How can I escape this?

Comment: You don't. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0):

Can try to use backtick. A backtick is not a quotation sign. It has a very special meaning. Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed).
Attection is executed before the main command

hope it helps you in your problem